# MySQL two columns ordering

Tags: mysql

I have table news having start_date and end_date

[image]

I want result as follows

[image]

Both column datatype is year

Comment: Can you explain in human language the logic behind your desired transformation? Where did the row with `end_date` of 2019 and `start_date` of 2016 go?

Comment: @mustaccio It will comes at 3rd place after start_date of 2017 and end_date of 2019

Answer (score 2):

Your sample would be achieved by

```
ORDER BY end_date DESC, start_date DESC
```